# interpolate between texture buffer openGL

Tags: android, animation, opengl-es

I am trying to do some animation. I have a initial vertex value and texture buffer value and also final texture and vertex value. Now i want to apply some kind of transformation and animation between those two values. How can we achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

What interpolation? There are many types of interpolations.

One kind of interpolation is cross-fade effect. You can use the accumulation buffer to fade between two images. On each frame draw, you use alpha blending to draw a semi-transparent of your final image on the accumulation buffer, and then blit them to the screen buffer.

Comment: Got it done. If anyone interested in answer do let me know. Will be happy to help